# issues with selenium, not finding by xpath on iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests, web-scripting

I'm doing web scraping with Selenium in python and I need to click a button to extract some data this button is inside of an iframe which I already switched (switch.to_frame()) and Selenium still doesn't find by XPath

```
this is the code:


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
import os
import time

def ingresar_licitaciones():
    resultado='3540-102-L123'
    options = Options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://www.mercadopublico.cl/Home")
    driver.maximize_window()
    inicio_sesion = driver.find_element("xpath","//button[@value]")
    inicio_sesion.click()

    clave_unica = driver.find_element("xpath","//img[@class]")
    clave_unica.click()

    usuario_run = driver.find_element("xpath","//input[@id='uname']")
    usuario_claveunica = driver.find_element("xpath","//input[@id='pword']")

    ingresar_run = "123456778-9"
    ingresar_clave_unica = "password"

    usuario_run.send_keys(ingresar_run)
    usuario_claveunica.send_keys(ingresar_clave_unica)

    ingresar = driver.find_element("xpath","//button")
    ingresar.click()

    entidad = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(('xpath','//span[@class="wrap-td"]')))
    entidad.click()

    ingresar2 = driver.find_element("xpath",'//a[@class="btn btn-pri"]')
    ingresar2.click()

    menu_licitaciones = driver.find_element("xpath",'//img[@alt="Expand Licitaciones "]')
    acciones = ActionChains(driver)
    acciones.move_to_element(menu_licitaciones).perform()

    oferta_licitaciones = driver.find_element("xpath",'//a[@href="/BID/Modules/RFB/NEwSearchProcurement.aspx"]')
    oferta_licitaciones.click()

    driver.switch_to.frame("fraDetalle")

    id_licitacion = resultado

    ingresar_id_licitacion = driver.find_element("xpath",'//input[@id="txtProcCode"]')
    ingresar_id_licitacion.send_keys(resultado)

    boton_id_licitacion = driver.find_element("xpath",'//input[@id="btnSearchByCode"]')
    boton_id_licitacion.click()

    time.sleep(10)

    ver_ficha = driver.find_element("xpath",'//input[@id="rptAcquisition_ctl01_itbnVerAdquisicion"]') # This is the problem, doesnt find the input 
    ver_ficha.click()
```

The error is in line 51 and says

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 ingresar_licitaciones()

File c:\Users\angel\Desktop\Licitacion\funciones_webscraper.py:155, in ingresar_licitaciones()
    151 boton_id_licitacion.click()
    153 time.sleep(10)
--> 155 ver_ficha = driver.find_element("xpath",'//input[@id="rptAcquisition_ctl01_itbnVerAdquisicion"]')
    156 ver_ficha.click()

File c:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:740, in WebDriver.find_element(self, by, value)
    737     by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    738     value = f'[name="{value}"]'
--> 740 return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

File c:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:346, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    344 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    345 if response:
--> 346     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    347     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    348     return response

File c:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:245, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    243         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id="rptAcquisition_ctl01_itbnVerAdquisicion"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.201); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00DAA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x00D3C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00C45358]
    (No symbol) [0x00C709A5]
    (No symbol) [0x00C70B3B]
    (No symbol) [0x00C9E232]
    (No symbol) [0x00C8A784]
    (No symbol) [0x00C9C922]
    (No symbol) [0x00C8A536]
    (No symbol) [0x00C682DC]
    (No symbol) [0x00C693DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0100AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0104A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0104456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E351E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00D45F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00D42328]
    (No symbol) [0x00D4240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00D34FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x773800C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77867B1E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77867AEE+238]
```

I would like help with the click of that button to keep going with my code and execute the function`

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoKnO.png here is the image to the html code that i want to acces, i hope now is simplier my question

Comment: At which line are you exactly stuck? What errordo you see?

Comment: Can you show the html of the element you are trying to find?

Comment: You're making us guess where the problem is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: already add some things i hope its enough to get help,
I'd appreciate it

Comment: That element does not exist.  So, the question is, why did you _expect_ that element to exist?  Can you show us an html sample that illustrates the element you expected to find?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoKnO.png this is the element im talking about it's inside the iframe a mentioned earlier